# how can i get real time log in .bat file at QGIS & PlugIn with python PyQT4

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess, qgis

i try to get real time log in batch file with python, then show it to QGIS Plugin real time. 
( .bat file is run -jar file )

i success logging but not real time log in QGIS
because QGIS is stopped by .bat file 
( it is not completed )

```
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        'C:/val/start.bat',
        shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        #close_fds=True,
        #creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS
    )


    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
        self.dockwidget.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(line)
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(line, tag="Validating", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
        if not line : break

    self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Validating", "Validating is completed")

except:
    self.dockwidget.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("##############Error##############")
```

i want not pause QGIS on running .bat file
and logging in QGIS Plugin by real time

how can i do that??

Comment: Why do you have an endless loop? what is the reason behind this, because maybe this is what is keeping QGIS to shut down.